# Is the T-38 wing strong enough to carry any weapons?

Tags: trainer, t-38

First, let me just clarify that I'm aware the T-38 doesn't have the necessary hardware to actually support firing weapons -- it doesn't have a fire control radar, for one. In any case, I'm still curious:

**Question:** What are the main differences between the wing for the T-38 and F-5? Is the T-38 wing strong enough to carry weapons, such as a couple AIM-7's?

From an answer at [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-the-F-5-and-T-38) it is claimed the wing is stronger on the F-5 to support hard points for weapons. However, is this true? There are no references on the Quora answer. I'd love to see some kind of decent reference, details about the wing, loading capacity, structure, diagrams?

These are pretty old aircraft and I would have thought the details for the wings are publicly available, but perhaps, they simply are not? If that is the answer, I'll accept that. Having good sources for details about wings might also aid those developing accurate simulators, like DCS, etc. E.g. how much does the wing flex under a certain load and when does it break, on the F-5? Is this publicly available? Not trying to roll many questions into one here, just trying to justify the question at all.

From the following diagrams it seems like the F-5 has a leading edge extension to the wing, but it isn't possible (at least for me) to say anything else about the wing profile or its strength.

[image: T-38 3-view]

[image: F-5 3-view]

Comment: While this does not relate to the wing, the AT-38B is/was weapons capable, on a centerline pylon. https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Visit/Museum-Exhibits/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/196733/northrop-at-38b-talon/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The T-38's wing is strong enough to carry weapons without a significant weight increase.
Not because of any special design for that.
It's just that any jet's wing is strong enough to carry an additional load mid-span, because that doesn't add to the spanwise load.

Structurally, you can think of an aircraft as resting on its wings, placed on a very soft foam bed. Hanging weight in the middle of the wings or at the wingtips doesn't just not increase the stress, it actually decreases some of the stresses in the wing.

Hardpoints still have to be built into the wing, though. You can't just attach the missiles to the lower surface with suction pads or adhesive tape. And there is some possibility of destructive flutter modes if the job isn't done right.

But nothing about the T-38's wing prevents it from being done right, at minimal weight increase. Some engineering and testing to be done to check the wing's behavior. In other words, it's easy to build an armed variant of the T-38, and takes some effort to add missiles to an already-built one.

Answer (score 9):

The wings are strong enough for a munition, because they hold the weight of the whole aircraft via the landing gear.

Adding a few hundred pounds of missile, or a 500 lb bomb on each side, would not be an issue.

Of course the hardpoints and circuitry would need to be built in to the wing. But the actual wing would be plenty strong enough.

Comment: Even if the landing gears aren't there the wings of all aircraft **MUST** be capable of holding the weight of the whole aircraft in flight. The point of the average center of lift on the wings is the least stressful part to add weight in flight

Comment: I would have thought the point of maximum bending moment, I.e. the wingtip, would be the place to reduce bending stress.

Answer (score 6):

There are plenty of things that do make a difference and "strength" isn't really enough of a discriminator. In particular, adding things to wings can cause divergent aerodynamic oscillation (aka "flutter"). Reaction loads (e.g. from release / jettison) are local strength and fatigue issues, not always at the wing-level.

Edit: It isn't easy to work out whether flutter is an issue for any given configuration. That usually needs wind-tunnel / CFD level analysis, followed by instrumented flight test. The specific weapon (or other store - e.g. fuel tanks, cargo pod), rack configuration and location on the wing make a lot of difference. Adding stiffness (e.g. strengthening for local reaction loads) can make things worse or better. The only thing you can safely say before that analysis and test program is "flutter might be a problem, and if it is, the wings might rip off".

Comment: This is a valid observation, but it doesn't answer the question. Would the T-38 wings suffer from flutter?

Comment: The T-38 wings might do - added some edits.